# Changing popover button icon

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have doubt regarding bootstrap popover icon. If I clicked on popover button, I need to change icon of popover button to close icon and then if I press close icon then popover button icon need to change as default. I have attached images, I think it may help you.

By default popover button like as follows in the image
[see popover button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5C5P.jpg)

If I press popover button then it need to appear as follows in the image
[see icon has changed to close symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syxyn.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(".container").on("click",function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("change").parent().toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.menu{width:35px;
      height:38px;
      background-color:#00BCD5;
      padding:8px 10px;
      border-radius:100px;
      transition: 0.4s;}
.menu.open{
   height:150px;
}
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 5px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 5px);
}
.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}
.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
<div class="container" >
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

###### PM Commission

10%

###### Entity Commission

10%

">

popover is not working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).